# Is "become" both stative and dynamic verb

Tags: verbs, stative-verbs

Since it is OK to say "The house is becoming more expensive", *become* can be a dynamic verb for dynamic verbs allow the progressive tense. I wonder if *become* is also considered as a stative verb.

Answer (score 2):

*Become* is a contraction of *come to be*, which is a general ***Inchoative*** (change of state) predicate,
like *start, finish, end, begin,* and *continue*.

- *He became tired ~ He came to be tired* - He was not tired at time *t₀*, and he was tired at (later) time *t₁*.
- *He became a doctor ~ He came to be a doctor* - not a doctor at time *t₀*, and doctor at (later) time *t₁*.

Inchoatives change states, but change between states may be gradual, allowing for optional continuous constructions, under the right circumstances. These all mean the same thing, for instance:

- *The value of the house continues to rise every year.*
- *The value of the house is continuing to rise every year.*
- *The value of the house becomes higher every year.*
- *The value of the house is becoming higher every year.*

Comment: But *start, finish, end, begin*, and *continue* are all considered as dynamic verbs, and *become* is different.

Comment: All of these inchoative verbs have their own individual differences. _Become_ is indeed different, but that doesn't set it apart; they're all different from one another. Each is adapted to a different set of contexts and usages.

Comment: *Become* is considered as both stative and dynamic, while all others are only dynamic.

Comment: If you say so. I don't know who's doing your considering for you.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know  what do you mean by dynamic but I think  you mean action verb and a state verb

Become can be used in the progressive forms and other forms too.So  it  can be a state verb but may not be a dynamic verb though it is used in the progressive forms but **know** and **understand** can be pasivized though they are not usually used in the progressive forms.

**Become can not be used in the passive voice.It is always intransitive like come and go and usually talks about a change of state.Anyhow, it is a special verb**.

**He became  a doctor**

**He became famous**

> **Previously, he was a doctor.Later he became a professor**.(change of state in the past)
>
> **I will become a doctor.**( future time)
>
> **English is becoming difficult for me  day by day**.( present progressive)
>
> **It is becoming cold**( present progressive)

Unlike verbs concerning mind such as **know**, **understand** etc. *become* can be used in the progressive forms in all tenses.

Here is the link.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/become

Answer (score 0):

The verbs look, sound, appear, became can all describe a state.i.e. be a stative verb.

- He **became red** in the face all of a sudden.
- They **became rich** because they worked hard.